# Interrupt Handler behaving wierdly

Tags: c, arduino, interrupt-handling

I am using a code as shown. I have a buzzer connected to pin 14. The function 'Sound_Play()'(produces sound for 0.5 secs) does its work only when encountered the second time inside the loop.

```
void loop() { 
inside_loop=1;
TCCR1A=0;        //initialize Timer1 for 1sec duration
TCCR1B=0X0D;
OCR1A=15624;
TIMSK1=0X02;

Sound_Play();      //This does not seem to work

block1=1; block2=0;
while(timer1_value>0)
{digitalWrite(13,HIGH);}
block1=0; block2=1;

Sound_Play();        //This works

while(timer2_value>0)
{digitalWrite(13,LOW);}
timer1_value=time1_sec;
timer2_value=time2_sec;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{ if (block1==1) {timer1_value--;}
else if (block2==1) {timer2_value--;}
}

void Sound_Play(){ //activate timer2 for producing sound for 0.5 secs
TCCR2B=0x07;
TCCR2A=0x02;
OCR2A=35;
TIMSK2=0x02;
counting=110;
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{ if(inside_loop)
{
if(counting>0){
digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
counting = counting-1;
}
else{
TIMSK2=0x00;     //deactivate timer2 on completing the time
digitalWrite(14,0);
}}
```

I tried using function once inside loop . It still made buzzer on only when encountered second time. I don't think the priority of the interrupts must be causing this.
Can please someone explain why this function does not make sound on everytime it is encountered?
Thanks!
Bhuvnesh

Comment: The most essential piece of program isn't here. Variables used used in both main program and ISR has to be volatile.

Comment: @KIIV Is volatile type really required even if compiler optimizations are off . And are they off by default in Arduino IDE? And what part should I post?

Comment: I just debugged the program and found out a curious cause for this malfunction. Actually, I have initialized the counter2 before setting counting=110, so what happens is the program jumps to ISR directly without setting counting=110 worked and disables it because initially counting=0 for the first time, but the second time the counting was already set to fifty(previously).  I changed the order of the two lines and it worked!